# How to compute the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ power of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How would I compute $\begin{pmatrix}-5&8\\-4&7\end {pmatrix}^5$ using the relationship between the diagonal matrices and the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ power of a matrix?

My lecturer gave the relation $A^k$=$P^{-1}D^kP$ where $D$ is the diagonalized form of the first matrix. Could somebody give a step by step by step solution to this please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Imagine that $A$ is diagonalizable, i.e, you can write $A = P^{-1}DP$ for some $P$ and diagonal $D$. Then,
$$
A^2 = \left( P^{-1}DP \right) \left( P^{-1}DP \right)
    = \left( P^{-1}D \left(P   P^{-1}\right) DP \right)
    = \left( P^{-1}D^2 P \right)
$$

Can you take this from here?

**EDIT** In response to the comments below, I am getting
$$
P = \pmatrix{1 & -1\\-1 & 2}, P^{-1}= \pmatrix{2 & 1\\1 & 1}, D= \pmatrix{-1 & 0\\0 & 3}
$$
so
$$
A^5 = \pmatrix{2 & 1\\1 & 1} \pmatrix{-1 & 0\\0 & 243} \pmatrix{1 & -1\\-1 & 2}
    = \pmatrix{-245 & 488\\-244 & 487}
$$

Comment: This is what I'm getting but the answer that I'm getting is incorrect and I've done the problem multiple times and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. The way I know it's wrong is because we have to use an online system for our homework that automatically tells us whether it's right or wrong but doesn't tell you why it's wrong.

Comment: @RyanMcGaha what are you using for $D$ and $P$?

Comment: I'm using D= $\big ($ $\begin {matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 3\\ \end {matrix}$ $\big )$ and P=$\big ($ $\begin {matrix} 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \end {matrix}$ $\big )$ .

Comment: if you see my answer, $P$ should consist of unit vectors. i.e. you should have $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}  \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \end{array} \right)$

Comment: @RyanMcGaha it sounds like the order is wrong, shouldn't you have $P = \pmatrix{1 & -1 \\1 & 2}$ with $P^{-1} = \pmatrix{2 & 1 \\1 & 1}$?

Comment: @gt6989b  If $ \ P \ $ is correct, you might want to check that inverse you gave...

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Typo, sorry, $P = \pmatrix{1 & -1\\-1 &2}$ and $P^{-1}$ is correct.

Comment: @RyanMcGaha Ryan, see the last update to the answer, I posted my numbers, do we agree?

Comment: Yes our numbers now match. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @ellya why do should unit eigenvectors be used? Can you show me source with this? I haven't seen this.

Comment: I think I was wrong, I **thought** $P$ was meant to formed of an orthonormal basis of eigen values, making $P^{-1}=P^T$, but I seem to be wrong.

Comment: As is clear from the above argument, it works as long as P is invertible, it doesn't rely on P being orthogonal

Comment: Looked into it more, basically what I was saying is right i.e. With unit eigenvectors, but it is not the only way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

It may help to know that the diagonal entries of $D$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, and the rows of $P$ are the corresponding eigenvectors of $A$, so calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, then $A^5=(P^{-1}D^5P)$

Comment: Why do you use unit eigenvectors? I haven't seen this.

Comment: I forgot we were not in the context of   a positive definite symmetric matrix.

Comment: Basically if $A $ was symmetric it would hold with unit eigenvectors etc.

Answer (score 1):

To find the diagonal form of the matrix you would calculated the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. $D$ is a diagonal matrix where the entries are the eigenvalues of $A$, $P$ is a matrix formed by the eigenvectors (each eigenvector is a column corresponding to the column its eigenvalue is in for $D$).