# How to determine $A^n$ based on the division of its characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Let $$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &1  & 1 & -1\\ 
 0&  1&  -1& 1\\ 
-1 &  -1&  1& 0\\ 
 -1&  -1&  -1& 2
\end{bmatrix} $$

I found its eigenvalues to be $1$ and $2$.

Its characteristic polynomial is $(\lambda - 1)^2(\lambda -2)^2$.

Its minimal polynomial is $(\lambda - 1)(\lambda -2)$.

Now I am asked to calculate the remainder of the Euclidian division of $(X-1)(X-2)$ by $X^n$ where $n \geq 1, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Here, I already struggle to do it.

Calculating the quotien of the division, I find $X^{\frac{2}{n}}-3X^{\frac{1}{n}}$ with a remainder of $2$, but this can't even be a quotient because a polynomial can't have non-natural powers.

How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compute the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ power of a matrix?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735532/how-to-compute-the-n-textrmth-power-of-a-matrix)

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is not a duplicate. The problem seen in that post isn't the same as mine. I know how to do matrix diagonalization. Here I am searching for the link between finding the remainder of a division and the diagonalization.

Comment: Actually, $SAS^{-1}=J=diag(2,2,1,1)$, so $A^n=S^{-1}J^nS$ as in the duplicate. You could edit the question and just ask about polynomials. For the formula for $A^n$ we do not need to calculate the remainder.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:  As you know, the satisfaction of its characteristic polynomial by matrix $A$ allows $A^n$ to be expressed as a linear combination of smaller powers of $A$.  This approach does not require a matrix to be diagonalizable, nor to find similarity transformations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're meant to divide $X^n$ by $(X-1)(X-2)$,  not $(X-1)(X-2)$ by $X^n$.

Then, the remainder has degree at most $1$ and so
$$
X^n = (X-1)(X-2)q(X) + aX+b
$$
Now evaluate at $X=1$ and $X=2$ and solve the linear system
$$
1^n = a+b, \quad 2^n = 2a+b
$$
to find $a,b$. This gives
$$
A^n = aA + bI = (2^n-1)A+(2-2^n)I
$$
because $(A-I)(A-2I)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

*A simple variant:*

The remainder in the division of $P(X)$  by $(X-a)(X-b)$ $\;(a\ne b)$  is the determinant
$$\frac1{a-b}\begin{vmatrix}P(a)&P(b)\\X-a&X-b\end{vmatrix}.$$
In the present case you obtain $$X^n\equiv 2^n(X-1)-(X-2)=(2^n-1)X+2-2^n\mod (X-1)(X-2).$$
Applying this congruence to $A$ yields
$$A^n=(2^n-1)A+(2-2^n)I.$$

Comment: How do you show that the remainder is the determinant?

Comment: Just taking $X-a$ and $X-b$ as a basis of polynomials of degree $\le1$ and solving for $R(X)=t(X-a)+u(X-b)$.