# Find the $100^{th}$ power of the matrix $\left( \begin{matrix} 1& 1\\ -2& 4\end{matrix} \right)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the $100^{th}$ power of the matrix $\left( \begin{matrix} 1& 1\\ -2& 4\end{matrix} \right)$.

Can you give a hint/method?

Comment: Diagonalize, then it's easy to take the 100th power.

Comment: Eigenvalues would be a bad idea.  You could get radical numbers.  Just use $M^n = \left(M^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\right)^2 \times M^{n \text{ mod } 2}$.

Comment: @DanielV What would be wrong with getting radicals?  The OP doesn't specify that he/she is looking for a computational answer rather than a concise symbolic representation (which is typical in a math course).  Is $(1+\sqrt{2})^{100} + (1-\sqrt{2})^{100}$ so much worse than $189482250299273866835746159841800035874$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$P= \begin {pmatrix} 1& 1\\ -2 & 4 \end {pmatrix} $$The key is to write the matrix $P $ in terms of a diagonal matrix $D $. Thus we wish to write $$P=ADA^{-1} $$ where $D $ is a diagonal matrix. Thus, $$P^n =AD^n A^{-1} $$ $D^n $ being very easy to compute, we find the values of $D $ and $A $ using eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

---

For more, you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735532/how-to-compute-the-n-textrmth-power-of-a-matrix). Hope it helps.

Comment: I like this answer a lot because it includes a top-level summary, giving the *relative importance* of the various steps you take to solve this, rather than just walking through the steps.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of the given matrix say $A$ is $x^2-5x+6$, the zeroes of whose are $2,3$. Thus there exist an invertible matrix $P$ such that $A=P\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0\\
0 & 3\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$. Hence $A^{100}=P\begin{pmatrix} 2^{100} & 0\\
0 & 3^{100}\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$, where $P = \begin{pmatrix}1 &1\\
2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes !!! I just realized that I forgot that..thanks for pointing it out...I will edit it accordingly.

Comment: I think your eigenvalues need to match the order of the eigenvectors in the matrix. You should swap one of them

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the [eigen decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) for the matrix and transform it into a diagonal matrix (for which computing powers is easy).

The eigenvectors of the matrix $M$ given by

$$
M = \left( \begin{matrix} 1& 1\\ -2& 4\end{matrix} \right)
$$

are:

$$
v_1 = \left ( \begin{matrix} 1\\ 2\end{matrix} \right) \qquad
v_2 = \left ( \begin{matrix} 1\\ 1\end{matrix} \right)
$$

giving us the change of base matrix $B$ as:

$$
B = \left( \begin{matrix} 1& 1\\ 2& 1\end{matrix} \right)
$$

The matrix, $\Gamma = B^{-1}MB$, is a diagonal matrix as such:

$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma &= B^{-1}MB \\ 
&= \left( \begin{matrix} -1& 1\\ 2& -1\end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} 1& 1\\ -2& 4\end{matrix} \right) \left( \begin{matrix} 1& 1\\ 2& 1\end{matrix} \right) \\ 
&= \left( \begin{matrix} 3& 0\\ 0& 2\end{matrix} \right) \\ 
\end{align}
$$

Now we compute $\Gamma^{100}$ which is easy since it is diagonalizable:

$$
\Gamma^{100} = \left( \begin{matrix} 3^{100} & 0\\ 0& 2^{100}\end{matrix} \right) 
$$

Now we convert it back to the standard basis:

$$
\begin{align}
M^{100} &= B\Gamma^{100}B^{-1} \\
&= \left( \begin{matrix} 1& 1\\ 2& 1\end{matrix} \right)  \left( \begin{matrix} 3^{100}& 0\\ 0 & 2^{100}\end{matrix} \right)  \left( \begin{matrix} -1& 1\\ 2& -1\end{matrix} \right) \\ 
&= \left( \begin{matrix} -3^{100} + 2^{101}& 3^{100} - 2^{100}\\ -2\cdot 3^{100} + 2^{101} & 2\cdot 3^{100} - 2^{100}\end{matrix} \right) \\ 
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $A=PDP^{-1}$ then $A^{100}=PD^{100}P^{-1}$

Then we know that $M=\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1\\ -2& 4\end{bmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $\lambda=(3,2)$ and eigenvector matrix P=$\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$ therefore $D=\begin{bmatrix} 3&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$

Now apply $A^{100}=PD^{100}P^{-1}$

$D^{100}=\begin{bmatrix} 3^{100}&0\\0&2^{100}\end{bmatrix}$

$P^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} -1&1\\2&-1 \end{bmatrix}$

Then $M^{100}=(-515377520732011328501159929309162469708701111249, 
  515377520732011329768810529537391871205404316625,
-1030755041464022659537621059074783742410808633250, 
  1030755041464022660805271659303013143907511838626)$