# Computation of 10th power of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been given the following matrix $A$. I am required to find 10th power of $A$.

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
 3 & 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 4 & 2 \\
 -1 & -1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I tried using Cayley Hamilton Theorem and found the characteristic polynomial as:
$t^3-8t^2+20t-16=0$.From here I find myself unable to compute the said power. Long division is daunting to me in this case. Please suggest how to go about it. The eigenvalues come out to be $2$( double) and $4$.

Comment: If $A=\Lambda D \Lambda^{-1}$, then $A^{10}=\Lambda D^{10} \Lambda^{-1}$

Comment: Is your question more about finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial? Or are you asking what to do after you diagonalize the matrix?

Comment: If it's the latter, then [this may answer your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/735535/165060).

Comment: @Elliot Yu Since it was a question asked in exam, therefore my worry is that  time constraints may  not allow me to go for diagonalization. After coming up with the characteristic polynomial, how to go about it?

Comment: @Elliot Yu Also after coming up with matrix formed by eigenvectors, that will have to be inverted as well. I fear that I will be having this much time.

Comment: @HARVEERRAWAT Sorry I'm not sure what you're asking. Diagonalizing the matrix and then using the method in the linked answer is the fastest method of taking the 10th power of this matrix that I can think of. If you are asking how to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial, then you might try factoring it using polynomial long division. If you have difficulty with that, then may I suggest asking a separate question and elaborating on what you find difficult?

Comment: @HARVEERRAWAT As for inverting the matrix of eigenvectors, you can choose the eigenvectors to be orthonormal, so that the basis change is orthogonal, in which case the inverse of the basis change is just the transpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eigenvectors for this matrix come out to be
$$\left( \begin{array}{c} -1\\1\\0\end{array} \right),\left( \begin{array}{c} -1\\0\\1\end{array} \right), \left( \begin{array}{c} -1\\-2\\1\end{array} \right)$$
To diagonalize the matrix, if $A = SDS^{-1}$, then
$$S = \left( \begin{array}{c c c} -1&-1&-1\\1&0&-2\\0&1&1\end{array} \right), A = \left( \begin{array}{c} 2&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&4\end{array} \right)$$

Then $A^{10} = SD^{10}S^{-1}$, and finding 10th power of a diagonal matrix is trivial.

Can you take it from here?